# New limits for substitution in multiple integrals

Tags: integration, substitution, multiple-integral

Considering the following integral of the function $\rho(t-u)$:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^L\int_0^L\rho(t-u)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}

Making the substitution $s = t - u$:

\begin{equation}
 \int_0^L\int_0^L\rho(t-u)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}t = \int_0^L\int_{t-L}^t \rho(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}

My question is how are the new limits $s = t-L$ and $s = t$ obtained? I am unable to understand this.

Comment: When $u = 0$, $s = t$ and when $u = L$, $s = t-L$. In addition, $du = -ds$. So you have your integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{align}\int_{0\leqslant t\leqslant L}\int_{0\leqslant u\leqslant L} \rho(t-u)~\mathsf d u~\mathsf d t ~&=~ \int_{0\leqslant t\leqslant L}\int_{0\leqslant t-s\leqslant L} \rho(s)~\lvert\frac{\partial (t-s)}{\partial s}\rvert\mathsf ds~\mathsf dt && u\gets t-s\\[1ex]&=~\int_{0\leqslant t\leqslant L}\int_{t-L\leqslant s\leqslant t}\rho(s)~\mathsf d s~\mathsf dt\\[3ex]\therefore\qquad\int_0^L\int_0^L \rho(t-u)~\mathsf d u~\mathsf dt~&=~\int_0^L\int_{t-L}^t\rho(s)~\mathsf d s~\mathsf d t \end{align}$